# Data-bind "attr" doesn't work (?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

### The Goal

Read the `data-product-id` from `DOM` added by  KnockoutJS.

### The problem

I have the following markup:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Summary.products -->
<li data-bind="attr: { 'data-product-id': id }">
    <div class="product-summary-actions float-right">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini remove-item">
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product-summary-quantity">
        <h6 data-bind="text: infoComposition"></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="product-summary-description">
        <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
    </div>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

As you can see, there is a data-bind at the first line after the comment with `attr` binding. Look:

```
<li data-bind="attr: { 'data-product-id': id }">
```

When I check my DOM using Chrome's console, I have the following:

```
<li data-bind="attr: { 'data-product-id': id }" data-product-id="1">...</li>
```

As you could see, `data-product-id` was *successfully* applied. But, when I have to make an interation with him, *no success*.

There is a function in my application that is responsible to check if an item exists on my Products Summary, and the following loop does this:

```
$(element).each(function () {
    var $productId = $(this).closest("li").data("product-id"),
    $match = $(".summary")
             .find("li[data-product-id=" + $productId + "]").length > 0;
     console.log($match);
});
```

Always the return is *false*. In other words, seems that jQuery doesn't consider the `data-product-id` generated by KnockoutJS because if I manually add the `data-product-id` attribute to my items (like the following markup), all works fine.

```
<!-- ko foreach: Summary.products -->
<li data-product-id="1">
    <div class="product-summary-actions float-right">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini remove-item">
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="product-summary-quantity">
        <h6 data-bind="text: infoComposition"></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="product-summary-description">
        <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
    </div>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

### Okay... Code

My *necessary* HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-small add"
        title="Add to comparison list">
    <i data-bind="attr: { class: ProductLayout.existsAtSummary($element) ? 
                  'icon-minus' : 'icon-plus' }">
    </i>
</button>
```

My JS:

```
function ProductLayoutViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.itemQuantity = ko.observable("");
    self.itemQuantityValid = ko.computed(function () {
        var q = self.itemQuantity();
        return q != "0" && q != "00" && q != null && q != "";
    }, this);

    self.existsAtSummary = function (element) {
        $(element).each(function () {
            $productId = $(this).closest("li").data("product-id");
            $match = $(".summary")
                     .find("li[data-product-id=" + $productId + "]").length;

            if (!$match)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        });
    });
};

ViewModel = {
    Summary: new SummaryViewModel(),
    ProductLayout: new ProductLayoutViewModel()
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/ProductsSummary/List?output=json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var mappingOptions = {
            create: function (options) {
                return (new (function () {
                    this.finalMeasure = ko.computed(function () {
                        return this.quantity() > 1 ? 
                               this.measure() + "s" : this.measure();
                    }, this);

                    this.infoComposition = ko.computed(function () {
                        return this.quantity() + ' ' + this.finalMeasure();
                    }, this);

                    ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
                })());
            }
        };

        ViewModel.Summary.products = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
        ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
    }
});
```

**Someone knows how can I solve this problem? Thanks!**

Comment: Why not use use `data-productid="your id here"`? It looks so much cleaner than json-encoding data in data-fields.

Comment: When does your function run? What does the `$productId` contain?

Comment: you sure it isn't a timing issue, where the jquery is being run before the knockout bindings are finished being applied?

Comment: I didnt tried but what about `$match = $(".summary li").filter(function() { var data = $(this).data(); return (data.attr['produkt-id'] == $productId); });`

Comment: Please post the function which contains the `$(element).each(function () { .. }` and also your code from you call that function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have a timing problem there.

Please note, that knockoutjs first goes through your js models and then filles the view with content. So if you are testing or in your case iteration over some DOM structure, you run straight into a timing error.

Try to rethink what you are doing there. As knockoutjs is providing the html with data, you already have all data in your js code. To me this looks like a work-a-round.

eg:
Your template:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Summary.products -->
<li data-bind="attr: { 'data-product-id': id }">
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

in knockoutjs you already have a list of products and the particular product-id. So all you need to do is to check the length of your list? Or do I miss something there?

If I get it wrong, and you just want to trigger another javascript which is doing something when your list is rendered, try to trigger some event when knockoutjs has filled your page with content. Or trigger your javascript after the dom is ready.

Comment: All I need is to check if a `li` with some `data-product-id` have its length greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Accordling to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQv8T/), it should work.

Are sure you execute the $(element).each after applied bindings ?

JS :

```
var vm = { id:'myID-product'};    
ko.applyBindings(vm);    
var element = $("#myID").data("product-id");             
console.log(element);
```

View :

```
<li data-bind="attr: { 'data-product-id': id }" id="myID">
```

So, I think you should :

- Create the VM instance
- Apply binding
- Call an init function in which you call the $(element).each

Comment: The `$(element).each` is part of a function that is inside of my KnockoutJS ViewModel.

Comment: So the $(element).each is called when you create an instance your VM ?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say `Call an init function in which you call the $(element).each`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said the $(element).each is called when the VM instance is created.
What you need to do is to call the *$(element).each* later (after the ko.applyBindings).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're doing the $.each before your DOM is ready (before Knockout has made its modifications).

Take the each out of your ViewModel and put it in this code-block:

```
$(function() {
    $(element).each(function () {
        var $productId = $(this).closest("li").data("product-id"),
        $match = $(".summary")
                 .find("li[data-product-id=" + $productId + "]").length > 0;
        console.log($match);
    });
});
```