# CSS Attr binding to pseudo elements background image property

Tags: jquery, css

I have a data attribute on an html element

```
data-tmpltImage="{{swatchImgUrl}}"
```

my question is how can I set that elements ::before pseudo element's background image something the following...

```
.element::before
{
 background:url(attr(data-tmpltImage));
}
```

If this is not possible how can I achieve this using JQuery?

Comment: Sorry had cut / paste error originally.  I realize the attr binding to the background property will not work it is pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: a printscreen of the error will be useful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405226/data-bind-attr-doesnt-work and http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/23615290220/data-binding-using-data-attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to select pseudo elements as they are not part of the dom. For that reason, you can't apply a style to any pseudo element with js.

However, you can add css to the page like so:

```
var bg = $('.element').data('tmpltImage');
$('head').append('<style>.element::before{background-image: url(' + bg + ')}</style>');
```

Comment: So given the fact that each element in an array will have a different reference will this appending Style to head cause a bloat issue in DOM that will negatively impact performance?  Each element would need it's own <style> tag specific to it's unique Url.  But I image I could loop through each element in the li array and pull the attr and then append to the <head>  I will give this a try see if it works.  Thank You.

Comment: @tafaju Yes, there will be a performance impact, but you'll have to test it yourself to see how bad that is. I suspect it will not be noticeable unless you have a huge number of elements to loop over, and probably more so on mobile. Adding styles like this is considered bad practice, but that's the only way it can be done if you can't do it server-side.

Comment: I implemented the solution and the style tags are in place bound to the li's by ID but unfortunately it doesn't appear to be setting the background image.

Comment: Is each individual psuedo element addressable, it doesn't seem the background css attribute is being assigned unless I put it in the css file itself.

Comment: So performance is not an issue because I include all style statements in a single style tag with no whitespace but it doesn't not seem to be setting the attribute correctly even though the syntax is the same as when I bind it to all elements of a particular type in the main css file.

Comment: @tafaju If you need further help with it, post a link to the site, or create a jsfiddle.